# Windows - User specific VPN

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, windows-server-2016

Is it possible to run a VPN client for a specific user only?

I'm renting a VPS with Windows Server 2016 and want certain users to run a VPN client, while others should use the standard network interface.
Sadly it seems that starting the VPN client on one user changes the routes globally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible under some conditions :

1. The VPN must allow [Split tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling)
2. The VPN must not change the default route in the
   [Routing table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table),
   or that default route must be reestablished after the connection to the VPN
3. The user in question can communicate with servers on the VPN
   by using their IP address
   (the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) can help here).

If you to avoid this problem, there is the old trick of this specific user
to run the VPN inside a virtual machine, therefore not impacting the
other users or the global Routing table.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has the construct of a Per user as well as an All user VPN. If you are using Windows InBuilt VPN Capabilities and have it such that it is per User along with not having to make the Default route change. It should work fine per user.

If that does not work though, if you can share more details about the configuration. The routing table as well as what is not working that will help with the next step of debugging.